# How to learn more than one concentration at character creation?

Tags: deadlands-classic

According to the Deadlands Classic Player's Guide, it's clear that you can (and must) select a concentration when selecting an aptitude that has them. But, it also says:

> Your character can learn additional concentrations of a skill for a flat 3 bounty points.

You only have *aptitude* points to spend at character creation, not *bounty* points (as far as I can tell), so are you not able to get more than one concentration for an aptitude at character creation? How does that work for things like language or academia? Is there an official ruling on this or at least a good house rule for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 70, in the character creation summary, in Step Three:

> As a man who makes his living dispensing his own kind of justice from the end of a gun, Ronan is a student of all forms of slug throwing weaponry. For **an additional 6 Aptitude points, we buy him two other shootin' concentrations**, *shootin': rifles* and *shootin': shotguns*

So, there you go: you can buy them for 3 aptitude points apiece. I'd guess that Bounty Points on page 38 is either a typo or a misthink, since Bounty Points aren't explained until Chapter 5.